# Docker Sonarqube scanner error java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException

Tags: node.js, docker, github, sonarqube, github-actions

While scanning the node.js code using GitHub actions, the docker SonarQube giving error as below in the GitHub actions agent and also the node.js code is not reflected in SonarQube,

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @58065f0c
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    ... 49 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Sonarqube is running in Docker. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.